# Can I have different root URLs in the same app?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

In my DRF project, I have 2 apps, `Users` and `Products`. `Products` has 2 models: `Category` and `Product`. My root URL conf looks like this

```
api_urls = [
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(api_urls))
]
```

and the products.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.ProductListCreateAPIView.as_view())
]
```

I want my API scheme to be something like

```
/api/users/
/api/products/
/api/categories/
```

Right now, this works fine for the first two URLS, but obviously not the third, i.e. if I was to add

```
path('categories', views.CategoriesListCreateAPIView.as_view())
```

to my products.urls, the URL scheme would be

```
/api/products/categories/
```

My question is, is there someway to achieve the `/api/categories/` objective without splitting off `Category` into its own app? I feel as if it's too insignificant to warrant having its own app and should be in the same app as `Product`. Obviously, I guess I could just import the views directly in the root URL conf but that doesn't feel like a 'clean' solution. Should I be thinking of creating a separate App for Category? The Product model has a foreign key relation with Category and to me, it feels as if 2 separate Apps would just be complicating things.

Comment: There's no fundamental reason why you would need to split this into different apps. Django apps is just a convenient way to structure your code, and namespace your db tables. Django rest framework includes its own url router that adds extra features on top of the underlying django routing. This is exactly the use case for the drf router. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Comment: @HåkenLid Could you provide a working example of this scenario with the Router?

Comment: This looks to me like a pretty typical API structure, so the example in the official docs that I liked to should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up opting for the following approach: Instead of using a single `urls.py` in my `Products` app, I created a URL module inside the app and added two `urlconfs` in it, one for each of `Category` and `Product`.

```
#product/urls/producturls.py

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.ProductListCreateAPIView.as_view())
]

#product/urls/categoryurls.py

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.CategoryListCreateAPIView.as_view())
]
```

Then I `include()` both in my root `urlconf`

```
api_urls = [
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('products/', include('products.urls.producturls')),
    path('categories/', include('products.urls.categoryurls'))
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(api_urls))
]
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to recognise you have some conflicting requirements; you want to do something unusual (two separate root paths in the same app) but you also want to keep it "clean".

The cleanest solution I can think of is not to use a prefix at all when including the app urlconf, but set it within the file as you do for the api prefix. So:

```
path('', include('products.urls'))
```

then

```
product_patterns = [
  path('', views.ProductListCreateAPIView.as_view()),
  ...
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('categories', views.CategoriesListCreateAPIView.as_view()),
    path('products/', include(product_patterns)
]
```

Comment: What would you recommend in this scenario? Should Categories be a separate App?